# Как в jsp передать через "FORM ACTION" в самого себя поля(переменные)?

Tags: jsp, form, action

Ради интереса пытаюсь сделать так и получаю null. Хотя если передать на другой jsp всё нормально принимается. Что я делаю не так? Может это не правильный подход?

**CreateGame.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="CreateGame.jsp" method="POST">
    <p>Player1: <input type="text" name="player1"/></p>
    <p>Player2: <input type="text" name="player2"/></p>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" name="date"/></p>
    <p>Status: <input type="text" name="status"/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm"/></br>
    </form>

    <% 
        String player1 = request.getParameter("Player1");
        out.println(player1);


     %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имена параметров чувствительны к регистру. Если вы передаёте параметр через `input name="player1"`, то и получать надо `request.getParameter("player1")`, а не как у вас (`"Player1"`).

Comment: Огромное вам СПАСИБО!(жаль не могу вам пока плюсик поставить) Вы только что заставили меня почувствовать себя полнейшим нубом. Но при этом я счастлив. :) Пойду напьюсь.

Comment: @Георгий На здоровье :) Хоть вы и не можете голосовать, вы можете отметить ответ принятым (нажав на галочку).